# add_image_size() in custom theme is not generating and saving any thumbnail

Tags: media-library, images

I am creating a custom theme (`WP version: 5.2.2`). In `functions.php` I added a few custom image sizes in the following way:

```
function abhijaan_theme_setup() {
   function abhijaan_theme_setup() {
      if( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ){
         ...
         add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
         ...
         if( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
           add_image_size( 'abhijaan-blog-list-thumbnail', 100, 100, true );
           add_image_size( 'abhijaan-single-page-across', 600, 200, true );
           add_image_size( 'abhijaan-medium-thubnail', 300, 300, true );
           add_image_size( 'abhijaan-small-thumbnail', 75, 75, true );
           add_image_size( 'abhijaan-sidebar-thumbnail', 51, 51, true );
           add_image_size( 'abhijaan-postcard-thumbnail', 120, 70, true );
           add_image_size( 'abhijaan-slider', 1366, 180, true );
           add_image_size( 'abhijaan-home-banner', 1366, 500, true );
         }
       }
   }
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'abhijaan_theme_setup' );
```

Original images are saving fine inside `wp-content/uploads/2019/08` but no thumbnail!

I am uploading all my images via `Media Library` for now.

What I am doing wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

Try t0 Regenerate thumbnails by using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: Regeneration is of course an option. But it would be nice if I don't use any plugin for this just because I am just creating my theme and would like to know the exact reason why the thumbnails are not saving. Can you please give me some idea on this?

Comment: You have to use it once, I don't think there is any other option, you don't need to do this again and again, just once after you add/edit add_image_size code, it's needed.

Comment: ok, I will try :)